# Ubuntu 22.04 stocks with 60 HZ Resolution option (Monitor supports up to 120)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display-resolution, monitor

I formatted my laptop today (dell g7 with Nvidia 1050 TI 4GB graphics chip).
Was using ubuntu 20.04 for 3 years now and everything was going fine, but on the new install (22.04) the laptop monitor refresh rate (which goes up to 120hz) just gets stuck with the 60hz option.
I already made sure I was using the latest version of the nividia drivers (530), and on the external monitor I can use the frequency of 144 normally.
This functionality has always been plug and play since version 18.04 and in windows it is being recognized normally.
How can I get this refresh rate to be recognized?

[image: Display Settings]

[image: Driver used]

[image: nvidia-smi output]

[image: System Information]

Thanks!